# repeating test cases using testng in specific order TestA -> TestB -> TestC -> TestA -> TestD

Tags: testng

I want to be able to execute test cases in this specific order where in each one is dependent on the previous one. Note that TestA and TestC is going to be executed again in this sequence. How can I do that using testng and Java.

TestA -> TestB -> TestC -> TestA -> TestX -> TestC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to run the same test many times during one run.

Instead, you can have:

```
TestA -> TestB -> TestC -> TestD -> TestX -> TestY
```

where `TestD` and `TestY` are just calling `TestA` and `TestC` methods.

Then, you just have to configure dependency between methods: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods