# Reusing @Test methods in testNG file

Tags: selenium, automation, testng

I have @Test method which needs to be re-executed after running few other @Test methods in testNG file. How can i achive this.

Please note i can t use other annotation like @BeforeTest @AfterTest in my set-up

```
@runTest
@VerifyPage
@VerifyTable
@runTest
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [repeating test cases using testng in specific order TestA -> TestB -> TestC -> TestA -> TestD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402120/repeating-test-cases-using-testng-in-specific-order-testa-testb-testc-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said on [repeating test cases using testng in specific order TestA -> TestB -> TestC -> TestA -> TestD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402120/repeating-test-cases-using-testng-in-specific-order-testa-testb-testc-t/33409349)

> It is not possible to run the same test many times during one run.
>
> Instead, you can have:
>
> ```
> TestA -> TestB -> TestC -> TestD -> TestX -> TestY
> ```
>
> where `TestD` and `TestY` are just calling `TestA` and `TestC`
>   methods.
>
> Then, you just have to configure dependency between methods:
>   http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods

So in your case, combined with `dependsOnMethods`:

```
@runTest
@VerifyPage
@VerifyTable
@runTest2 // which will just call @runTest method
```