# Testng - can't call the same @Test twice

Tags: testng

Hi please suggest me how can I call the same method marked by @Test annotation twice, the following case:

I have method "checkFirstRunResult" which dependsOnGroups "RunFeed" consisted with 3 methods.

So before "checkFirstRunResult" called, "RunFeed" group will be run.

After, if "checkFirstRunResult" passed we need to call another method "checkSecondRunResult" which depends on the same group of tests "RunFeed", so we expect the them to be triggered twice - but TestNG doesn't allow it - HOW CAN I DEAL WITH IT, PLEASE ANYT WORK AROUND.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [repeating test cases using testng in specific order TestA -> TestB -> TestC -> TestA -> TestD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402120/repeating-test-cases-using-testng-in-specific-order-testa-testb-testc-t)

Answer (score 0):

`dependsOnGroups` does not invoke a group of tests but simply declares a dependency of some tests that need to be run first (and by "running" I mean running once).

You will need to declare your tests multiple times (although you can have them call the same code so that you don't have to repeat yourself).

e.g.

1. Define a group of tests named "FirstRun"
2. Define `checkFirstRunResult` with `dependsOnGroups = "FirstRun"`
3. Define another group of tests named "SecondRun" where each test calls the same test code as the respective tests in "FirstRun" but are separate tests
4. Define `checkSecondRunResult` with `dependsOnGroups = "SecondRun"`
5. Make "SecondRun" depend on `checkFirstRunResult`. e.g.

   ```
   @BeforeGroups(groups = "SecondRun", dependsOnMethods = "checkFirstRunResult")
   public void prepareSecondRun() {
   }
   ```